# Not getting model data at the API side which is send by MVC controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api

[image: MVC controller]

[image: Web API method]

I am sending data from MVC controller to Web API controller but not getting it...
please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post your code **as properly formatted text** - not as screenshots - thank you

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: no, i am not getting any error